# Display Flash Message on button Click in Codeigniter using PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, message, buttonclick, flash-message

I have created a controller method that allows the user to change his/her login credentials(Username, password). On clicking the <kbd>Save changes</kbd> button, I would like to display a flash message indicating the status of the change process.

But I'm running into a trivial issue where the flash message is displayed only when I refresh the url and not as soon as the <kbd>Save changes</kbd> button is clicked.

**View**

```
<div id="login">
     <section class="clearfix">
     <form class="form-horizontal" method = "post" action="<?php echo site_url('studentDashboardController/saveUserLoginDetails');?>">
     <fieldset>

     <div style="width:1363px;margin-left:10px">
         <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msgLogin'); ?>
     </div>

     <!-- Form Name -->
          <legend>Edit Login Credentials</legend>

          <!-- Text input-->
          <div class="form-group">
               <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="username">Username</label>
               <div class="col-md-6">
                   <input id="username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="current" class="form-control input-md">
                   <span class="help-block">Enter a new Username (Leave Blank to only change the Password)</span>
               </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Password input-->
          <div class="form-group">
               <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="password">Password</label>
               <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="New password" class="form-control input-md">

               </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Password input-->
          <div class="form-group">
               <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
               <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" type="password" placeholder="Retype password" class="form-control input-md" required="">
               </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Button -->
               <div class="form-group">
                   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for=""></label>
                   <div class="col-md-4">
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/studentDashboardController/saveUserLoginDetails">
                             <button id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
                        </a>
                   </div>
               </div>

           </fieldset>
       </form>

    </section>
</div>
```

**studentDashboardController - saveUserLoginDetails()**

```
public function  saveUserLoginDetails()
{
     ...
     $msg = $this->studentprofileModel->saveUserLoginDetails($user,$this->input->post());
     $msgText = $msg['msg'];
     $msgType = $msg['type'];
     //Loading View
     $data1['details'] = $this->studentprofileModel->getUserDetails($username);
     if($msgType == "danger")
     {
         $this->session->set_flashdata('msgLogin', '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Failed</div>');
         echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$msgText.'")</script>';
     }
     else
     {
         $this->session->set_flashdata('msgLogin', '<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Success</div>');
     }

     redirect(base_url('index.php/studentDashboardController/editProfile',$data1));
}
```

**studentprofileModel - saveUserLoginDetails($user,$this->input->post())**

```
public function saveUserLoginDetails($uid,$post)
{
    $username = $post['username'];
    $password = $post['password'];
    $confirmPassword = $post['confirmPassword'];

    if ($username == null || $username == "") {
        if ($password == $confirmPassword) {
            $data = array(
                'password' => $password,
            );
            $this->db->where("uid", $uid);
            $this->db->update("sysuser", $data);
            $msg = "Password has been successfully changed";
            $type = "success";
            $msgData = array(
                'msg' => $msg,
                'type' => $type
            );
            return $msgData;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if($password == $confirmPassword)
        {
            $data = array(
                'password' => $password,
                'username' => $username
            );

            $this->db->where("uid", $uid);
            $this->db->update("sysuser", $data);
            $this->load->library('session');
            $sess_array = array(
                'username' => ''
            );
            $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
            $session_data = array(
                'username' => $username
            );
            // Add user data in session
            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_data);

            $msg = "Login Data have been successfully updated";
            $type = "success";
            $msgData = array(
                'msg' => $msg,
                'type' => $type
            );
            return $msgData;
        }
        else
        {
            $msg = "Password doesn't match";
            $type = "danger";
            $msgData = array(
                'msg' => $msg,
                'type' => $type
            );
            return $msgData;
        }
    }

}
```

This login details form that needs to be changed is actually a single tab out of 4 different tabs that are within a single view itself.(Full page code is provided in the code snippet for reference). Could this be an issue in not displaying the status message via the flash as soon as the button is clicked?

Also I've done the check as if the password and the confirm password inputs are matching. But, it doesn't seem to execute it properly. Instead I'm always getting a success message.

Any suggestions in this regard will be appreciated.

**Code snippet of Full View Code**

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Student Dashboard View</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
...
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url("assets/js/customScripts/taro/bootstrap-datepicker.js")?>"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="<?php echo base_url("assets/js/customScripts/taro/vendor/jquery-1.10.1.min.js")?>"><\/script>')</script>
<!--<script src="--><?php //echo base_url("assets/js/customScripts/taro/vendor/jquery.hashchange.min.js")?><!--"></script>-->
<script src="<?php echo base_url("assets/js/customScripts/taro/vendor/jquery.easytabs.min.js")?>"></script>

<script src="<?php echo base_url("assets/js/customScripts/taro/main.js")?>"></script>

<style>
    .entry:not(:first-of-type)
    {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .glyphicon
    {
        font-size: 21px;
    }
     .centered {
         position: fixed;
         left: 50%;
         transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     }
</style>


<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<script>window.html5 || document.write('<script src="<?php echo base_url("assets/js/customScripts/taro/vendor/html5shiv.js")?>"><\/script>')</script>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<p class="chromeframe">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">activate Google Chrome Frame</a> to improve your experience.</p>
<![endif]-->
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="">
        <!-- Header Start -->
        <header id="header">
            <div id="logo">
                <h2>
                    <?php foreach($details as $detail){?>
                        <?php echo $detail->name;?>
                    <?php }?>
                </h2>
            </div>
        </header>
        <!-- Header End -->
        <!-- Main Tab Container -->
        <div id="tab-container" class="tab-container">
            <!-- Tab List -->
            <ul class='etabs'>
                <li class='tab' id="tab-about">
                    <a href="#about"><i class="icon-user"></i><span> User Details</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class='tab'>
                    <a href="#resume"><i class="icon-file-text"></i><span> Edit Resume</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class='tab'>
                    <a href="#login"><i class="fa fa-cloud"></i><span> Login Credentials</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class='tab'>
                    <a href="#contact"><i class="icon-envelope"></i><span> Edit Contact Details</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- End Tab List -->
            <div id="tab-data-wrap">
                <!-- About Tab Data -->
                <div id="about">
                    <section class="clearfix">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" method ="post" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <?php echo form_open('studentDashboardController/saveUserDetails'); ?>
                            <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?>
                            <fieldset>

                                <!-- Form Name -->
                                <legend>User Details</legend>
                                ...
                                <!-- Button -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <a href="<?php echo base_url("/index.php/studentDashboardController/saveUserDetails"); ?>" >
                                            <button id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </fieldset>
                        </form>

                    </section>
                </div>
                <!-- End About Tab Data -->

                <!-- Resume Tab Data -->
                <div id="resume">
                    <section class="clearfix">
<!--                        <form class="form-horizontal" method = "post" action="--><?php //echo site_url('studentDashboardController/saveUserResumeDetails');?><!--">-->
                        <div class="g2">
                            <h3>
                                Work Experience
                            </h3>
                            ...
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/studentDashboardController/saveUserResumeDetails">
                                <button id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- End Resume Tab Data -->

                <!-- Login Tab Data -->
                <div id="login">
                    <section class="clearfix">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" method = "post" action="<?php echo site_url('studentDashboardController/saveUserLoginDetails');?>">
                        <fieldset>

                        <div style="width:1363px;margin-left:10px">
                            <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msgLogin'); ?>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Form Name -->
                        <legend>Edit Login Credentials</legend>

                        <!-- Text input-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="username">Username</label>
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                          <input id="username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="current" class="form-control input-md">
                          <span class="help-block">Enter a new Username (Leave Blank to only change the Password)</span>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Password input-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="password">Password</label>
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="New password" class="form-control input-md">

                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Password input-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
                          <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" type="password" placeholder="Retype password" class="form-control input-md" required="">

                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Button -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for=""></label>
                          <div class="col-md-4">
                              <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/studentDashboardController/saveUserLoginDetails">
                                <button id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
                              </a>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        </fieldset>
                        </form>

                    </section>
                </div>
                <!-- End LoginData -->

                <!-- Contact Tab Data -->
                <div id="contact">
                    ...
```

Comment: Flash data works with redirect only. redirect means Page reload

Comment: Since the button click is of type `submit` won't it work the same way? Or is there an alternative to display the flash message with the above methods?

Comment: Your code is too confusing. if you add form action, then no need to use `<a href="<?php echo base_url("/index.php/studentDashboardController/saveUserDetails"); ?>" >` on button.....

Comment: Once you save the `saveUserLoginDetails` then you have written redirect to `editProfile`. Is this works ??

Comment: Only when the page is refreshed. The intended is done. But as you've mentioned above, when I remove the anchor link and simply let the form action, it didn't work as there are 4 submit buttons since it's a page with 4 tabs and each tab is called upon using its division. How exactly can I refine this erroneous structure?

Comment: Its hard to suggest without looking your code. if this is in single page then i suggest you to use AJAX

Comment: @AbdullaNilam Could you please provide an example as an answer? I've provided the entire code in the question itself.